# How to Parallize the function fastly in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a list of 200 DataFrames and I am trying to apply a function but. I am trying to apply parallel function in python to speed up, but not able to get desire results.
Below is my code 
data is list of DataFrame with same columns and rows but different values

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
   def maxloc(data): 
        data['loc_max'] = np.zeros(len(data))
        for i in range(1,len(data)-1):  
            if data['value'][i] >= data['value'][i-1] and data['value'][i] >= data['value'][i+1]:
                data['loc_max'][i] = 1
        return data  

    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    results = pool.map(maxloc, [row for row in data])
    pool.close() 
    pool.join()
```

Comment: [scipy.signal.argrelextrema](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html) might be helpful for that task. It is already vectorized and therefore should be quite fast.

Comment: @cel Thanks, How can I use my own function maxloc in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation of maxloc that uses scipy.signal.argrelextrema and is much (in this example more than 1000 times) faster:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema 
np.random.seed(42)

def maxloc(data): 
    data['loc_max'] = np.zeros(len(data))
    for i in range(1,len(data)-1):  
        if data['value'][i] >= data['value'][i-1] and data['value'][i] >= data['value'][i+1]:
            data['loc_max'][i] = 1
    return data 

def maxloc_faster(data):
    loc_opt_ind = argrelextrema(df.value.to_numpy(), np.greater)
    loc_max = np.zeros(len(data))
    loc_max[loc_opt_ind] = 1
    data['loc_max'] = loc_max
    return data
```

Let's test it

```
values = np.random.rand(10000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': values})
np.all(maxloc_faster(df).loc_max == maxloc(df).loc_max)
# True

%timeit maxloc(df)
# 672 ms ± 39.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit maxloc_faster(df)
# 268 µs ± 12.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: thank you , when I run the code it gives me this error                                          loc_max[loc_opt_ind] = 1
IndexError: too many indices for array,                                                 As I used df.values to change DataFrame into array